# Twitter UserStream -- maximum number of client connections?

Tags: php, twitter, load-balancing

I'm working on a web app that uses information from the Twitter UserStream.

I'm currently completing all error handling, and it came to my attention that the Twitter UserStream only allows X connections per application. However, I cannot seem to find this value.

I am trying to set up a priority queue for idling and active streams to take offline during exessive client connections. What is the maximum number of connections per application? Cant find this..

As stated in the UserStream API:

> Each Twitter account is limited to only a few simultaneous User
>   Streams connections per OAuth application. Once the per-application
>   limit is exceeded, the account’s oldest connection from that OAuth
>   application will be terminated. An account logging in from too many
>   instances of the same OAuth application will continuously cycle their
>   connections as the applications reconnect and throw each other off the
>   service. Note that each application has its own allocation, so that
>   logging in from App1 doesn’t affect your App2 allocation, and visa
>   versa, but running too many copies of either App1 or App2 will cause
>   problems.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/user-streams

Comment: I think they are saying do not open and maintain too many streams. If they find out you are having too many streams per user, you will get a 420 error code and you will need to close some streams to regain stream access. I can't find a place in the docs which exactly say how many streams are allowed.

Comment: Right.. there's a maximum before denial, which is what I'm asking ;)

Comment: I'd just like to find that number so I can use it in my load balancer